# AWS IoT - Sending a message to a specific device of the fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I'm trying to play with AWS IoT to communicate with multiple identical devices.

So far, so good, all my devices are connected to it, and the only difference between them could be a single device ID (like a mac address or a serial number)

Now I'd like to send a message to a single specific device using its device ID and I don't know if there is a good way to do that?

I could make each device to subscribe to a topic like `/<DEVICE_ID>`, however it doesn't seem like a good practice especially if I have thousands of devices.

Plus, AWS discourages it as stated in the [AWS IoT documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-message-broker.html):

> **Note**
>
> We do not recommend using personally identifiable information in your
>   topics.

Is there a good way to handle this use case? Or is AWS IoT only useful to manage multiple devices at once?

Comment: did you find any information?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best practice for creating an MQTT topic.

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/

> Talking about your specific case

- Each device needs to have a unique identity to send a command to a particular device. In this case, you need to have **device_id** into your MQTT topic.
- You can use the following pattern to send a message for a destination device
- protocol_prefix / type_of_message / dest_id / message_id
- hexaiot/controldevice/d12345/x123
- Use **wild card character** at the time of device subscription to subscribe to the topic

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing a person's "personally identifiable information" (aka PII, like social security numbers - [check out examples from the US DOD](https://dpcld.defense.gov/Privacy/About-the-Office/FAQs/#1)) with "an ID that uniquely identifies a device" (aka a device ID).  I'm assuming you're looking for the latter.

The article you're linking no longer references PII, and there's a new-ish white paper from AWS: "Designing MQTT Topics for AWS IoT Core".  It talks about how to structure topics to send messages to specific devices.  Check out the "[Point-to-Point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/designing-mqtt-topics-aws-iot-core/mqtt-communication-patterns.html#point-to-point)" paragraph / graphic:

The graphic publishing to "room7" digital door sign seems close to what you want.

The topic is "sensor/occupancy/room7".
The publisher sends a message saying 70 seats are occupied {"count": "70"}.
The subscriber receives the message with the count of 70** occupied seats, and knowing that 92 seats are available, updates its display to say "22 seats available".

** The graphic in the article says {"count": "17"}, and I think that's a bug in the graphic (possibly someone saying "seventy" and the graphics person hearing "seventeen")

"room7" wouldn't be PII, so assuming you can find a way to identify your devices without using PII, AWS is recommending you follow this point-to-point pattern.